(oop in c++ by Robert Lafore) chapter 12: File streaming with objects & polymorphism. Program crashes after reading from file and trying to display
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
enum etype{managerr,scientistt,laborerr};
class employee
{
private:
    char name[40];
    int number;
public:
    virtual void getdata()
    {
        cout<<"Enter name: "; cin.get(name,40);
        cout<<"Enter number: "; cin>>number;
        cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    }
    virtual void putdata()
    {
        cout<<"Name is "<<name<<"\n& number = "<<number<<endl;
    }
    etype gettype();
    static void add();
    static void display();
    static void read();
    static void write();
};
int n=0;
employee *e[10];
class manager:public employee
{
private:
    char title[40];
    double dues;
public:
    void getdata()
    {
        employee::getdata();
        cout<<"Enter title: "; cin.get(title,40);
        cout<<"Enter dues: "; cin>>dues;
        cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    }
    void putdata()
    {
        employee::putdata();
        cout<<"Title is "<<title<<"\n& dues = "<<dues<<endl;
    }
};
class scientist:public employee
{
private: int pubs;
public:
    void getdata()
    {
        employee::getdata();
        cout<<"Enter amount of publications: ";
        cin>>pubs;
        cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    }
    void putdata()
    {
        employee::putdata();
        cout<<"& number of publications = "<<pubs<<endl;
    }
};
class laborer:public employee
{
};
void employee::add()
{
    char ch;
    label:
    cout << "Enter\nl for laborer\nm for manager\ns for scientist: ";
    cin >> ch;
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    switch (ch) {
        case 'l':
            e[n] = new laborer;
            break;
        case 'm':
            e[n] = new manager;
            break;
        case 's':
            e[n] = new scientist;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Wrong input try again!!!!";
            goto label;
    }
    e[n++]->getdata();
}
etype employee::gettype()
{
    if(typeid(*this)==typeid(manager))
        return managerr;
    else if(typeid(*this)==typeid(scientist))
        return scientistt;
    else if(typeid(*this)==typeid(laborer))
        return laborerr;
    else
        cout<<"Bad type";
}
void employee::display()
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Employee number "<<i+1<<" : ";
        etype type=e[i]->gettype();
        switch(type)
        {
            case managerr: cout<<"Manager"<<endl;      break;
            case scientistt: cout<<"Scientist"<<endl;  break;
            case laborerr: cout<<"Laborer"<<endl;      break;
        }
        e[i]->putdata();
    }
}
void employee::write()
{
    etype type;
    int size;
    ofstream file("Data.DAT",ios::binary);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        type=e[i]->gettype();
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&type),sizeof(etype));
        switch(type)
        {
            case managerr: size=sizeof(manager);     break;
            case laborerr: size=sizeof(laborer);     break;
            case scientistt: size=sizeof(scientist); break;
            default: cout<<"Can't write type"<<endl;
        }
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(e[i]),size);
    }
    file.close();
}
void employee::read()
{
    etype type;
    int size;
    ifstream file("Data.DAT",ios::binary);
    while(true)
    {
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&type),sizeof(etype));
        if(file.eof())
            break;
        switch(type)
        {
            case managerr:    e[n]=new manager;        size=sizeof(manager);      break;
            case laborerr:    e[n]=new laborer;        size=sizeof(laborer);      break;
            case scientistt:  e[n]=new scientist;      size=sizeof(scientist);    break;
            default: cout<<"Can't read type"<<endl;
        }
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(e[n]),size);
        n++;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int nn;
    char ch;
    do {
        label:
        cout << "press\n1.Add an employee\n2.Display all employees\n3.Write all employees\n4.Read all employees\n5.exit : ";
        cin >> nn;
        switch (nn) {
            case 1:
                employee::add();
                break;
            case 2:
                employee::display();
                break;
            case 3:
                employee::write();
                break;
            case 4:
                employee::read();
                break;
            case 5:
                exit(0);
            default:
                cout << "Wrong input!!!!!";
                goto label;
        }
    }while(true);
}

All the program works flawlessly except when I try to read the file and put it inside the variable again.
It crashes when I try to display the variables.
If I added any amount of employees then display them , they will be displayed without any problem then if I write them nothing happened.
After I close the program then try to read and display it crashes giving
(Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV))
I work with Clion on Mac.

We need a [mcve].

I couldn't put a minimal code so I had to put the whole code as most of it are intersected with each other unfortunately and because I am still a beginner so I can't understand how to make it smaller sorry for any inconvenience

Could you at least give a line number? the debugger should be able to tell you that.

file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(e[i]),size) You can't write non POD types as byte arrays

to be honest, I can't understand what you mean by "You can't write non POD types as byte arrays" , is there an article that I can read to understand why this can't occur or there is a way around this problem? I just did as the book said

The debugger says that the display function is the problem although it works flawlessly except for read part

@MohamedHelmy I can't understand what you mean by "You can't write non POD types as byte arrays -- But somewhere, you got the idea to write code like this.  No beginner just uses reinterpret_cast like this in a non-obvious (and wrong) way just by chance.  As mentioned, employee is a non-trivially-copyable type, so using reinterpret_cast to attempt to read or write it is invalid.

@PaulMcKenzie It is in the book I have just mentioned(oop in c++ by Robert Lafore), I just practice what I read and literally used the code that was written.

Then the book is wrong.  Your employee class is not trivially-copyable.  See this.  Do you see the output as 0 for employee and 1 for employee2?  What is the difference?  The difference is that employee has virtual functions, and having virtual functions means that the type is no longer trivially-copyable.  Only trivially-copyable types are "eligible" for reading and writing files using the raw read and write functions.

Also, I do not have this book, but I bet that the book did not show reading and writing classes that contain virtual functions this way.  Maybe you added the virtual functions yourself, and believed that you were not drastically changing how things worked w.r.t reading and writing?

It added the virtual functions, I didn't add it on my own , they just added it to be able to do polymorphism and call the function suitable for each derived class but it didn't mention the trivially copyable types and these things unfortunately I can picture you the code if you like

So do you have a book that is better than this one ?

Well, the book is wrong to show this to you.  Maybe when the author tried the code, it "worked" with their compiler and/or compiler settings.   But the code is fundamentally wrong, and you probably now paid the price for running the code on a compiler that isn't so forgiving.

Side note, this is C++ so for name use std::string not  char[40]; and for employee *e[10]; use std::vector<employee> employees; (use containers AND give your variables meaningful names). Your employee add ... reading data from input should be outside your class (separation of concerns)

Definitive C++ book guide and list

All in all, I think it is a good idea to learn C++ from an "up-to-date" source like learncpp.com, you will find a lot more info on how to use C++ at cppreference.com, and finally have a look at the C++ core guidelines to see how C++ should be used.

goto label; -- Why are you using goto here?  You could have used a do or a while loop, and only exiting the loop when the input is valid.

@PepijnKramer yeah ik string is better I just used the code as it is which was shown that it was wrong from the beginning as for vectors I didn't reach this part so I don't know how to use tbh

Also (binary) serialization is a very difficult thing to do right in C++ (a lot of potential for undefined behavior), if you are going to do that use a 3rd party library (e.g. protobuf/flatbuffers). Otherwise, serialize using a text based format. There are libraries for that too (e.g. nlohman json)

@PaulMcKenzie I put this because I didn't want the program to just close if I entered something wrong and to make the program returns to the part that was incorrect

@PepijnKramer I really don't know that much info and if binary serialization is very difficult or not, I just wanted to learn but I used an outdated source unfortunately so I guess I will find another up to date book that have the same amount of info

@MohamedHelmy -- If you want to read and write binary files, you must have a set layout for the file as to what each piece of data in the file represents.  You can't just simply write a blob of bytes without a plan of how the file is supposed to be formatted.  For example, you should write the type, then after that, you write the data that represents the type, not a blob of bytes.  Then when you read the file back, you read the type, and then you recreate the correct object based on the data.  That is the basis of object-serialization.

I put this because I didn't want the program to just close -- The point is that using goto in a program is not something you want to get into the habit of doing, with the ultimate result of using goto being spaghetti code.  There is no need for goto in the code you are showing.

Yeah I try not to use it at all but just in case the program will completely close and data weren't still written into the file , I used the goto to prevent this from happening that's it

The latest 4th edition of that book is 2001, this is very old book.

your code highlights some bad practices (raw owning pointers, raw arrays, static methods for no good reason, reinterpret_cast). I dont have the book available, but if you got all this from the book, you need to get a better one. urgently.
